# How to prevent Linux virtual machine to close/logout on VMWare?

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm trying to run a CentOS distribution on VMWare. Because the Linux is running calculations, i need this machine to never stop.

I've tried to run it in VMWare player, after 20 minutes of "innactivity", the session logout. I've tried to run it in VMWare Workstation, it does the same.

How do i manage the Linux or VMWare to prevent this logout ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago, if I can remember correctly, you need to do the following:

1. Shutdown the Virtual Machine.
2. Locate the Virtual Machine .vmx File.
3. Open The .vmx file in any text Editor.
4. Add This line: suspend.disabled = "TRUE"
5. Start the Virtual Machine again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it on VMWare Player but not on VMWare Workstation. It doesn't work on VMWare Player.

Comment: Quite strange.However, try to do these steps as well:

 - Login to CentOS CMD
 - Edit this file: /etc/systemd/logind.conf
 - Make sure you have this line in logind.conf: HandleLidSwitch=ignore
 - Save the file.
 - run this command: systemctl restart systemd-logind